# Error executing catkin_make: Invoking "make -j1 -l1" failed

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ros, catkin

I am new to ROS and got issues with catkin_make. At first it was working properly, when executing it inside a catkin workspace (catkin_ws). Then I created a catkin package inside src named rosjava without dependecies (catkin_create_pkg rosjava) and catkin_make began to fail:

```
~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make

Base path: /home/jon/catkin_ws

Source space: /home/jon/catkin_ws/src

Build space: /home/jon/catkin_ws/build

Devel space: /home/jon/catkin_ws/devel

Install space: /home/jon/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/jon/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j1 -l1" in "/home/jon/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] Built target _arbotix_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Digital

[  0%] Built target _arbotix_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SetupChannel

[  0%] Built target _arbotix_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Relax

[  0%] Built target _arbotix_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Analog

[  0%] Built target _arbotix_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SetSpeed

[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs

[  0%] Built target _arbotix_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Enable

[  3%] Built target arbotix_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs

[  3%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py

[  7%] Built target arbotix_msgs_generate_messages_py

[  8%] Generating Java gradle project from arbotix_msgs

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/genjava/cmake/../../../lib/genjava/genjava_gradle_project.py", line 11, in <module>
  import genjava

File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genjava/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
from .genjava_main import main, standalone_main

File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genjava/genjava_main.py", line 45, in <module>
import rosjava_build_tools

File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosjava_build_tools/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>

   import console

ImportError: No module named 'console'

arbotix_ros/arbotix_msgs/CMakeFiles/arbotix_msgs_generate_messages_java_gradle.dir/build.make:77: recipe for target 'arbotix_ros/arbotix_msgs/java/arbotix_msgs/build.gradle' failed

make[2]: *** [arbotix_ros/arbotix_msgs/java/arbotix_msgs/build.gradle] Error 1

CMakeFiles/Makefile2:931: recipe for target

'arbotix_ros/arbotix_msgs/CMakeFiles/arbotix_msgs_generate_messages_java_gradle.dir/all' failed

make[1]: *** [arbotix_ros/arbotix_msgs/CMakeFiles/arbotix_msgs_generate_messages_java_gradle.dir/all]
Error 2

Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed

make: *** [all] Error 2

Invoking "make -j1 -l1" failed
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? If so I would really appreciate receiving your help.

Thank you in advance,

Jon.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a dependency issue.
The line `ImportError: No module named 'console'` indicates `console` python package is missing.
 Install [console](https://pypi.org/project/console/) using pip.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer Shrijit Singh. I tried console instalation using pip and seems instalation did not worked properly:

```
~/catkin_ws$ pip install console

/home/jon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py:83: RequestsDependencyWarning: Old version of cryptography ([1, 2, 3]) may cause slowdown.
   warnings.warn(warning, RequestsDependencyWarning)
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting console
  Using cached console-0.990-py2.py3-none-any.whl (74 kB)
ERROR: Package 'console' requires a different Python: 2.7.12 not in '>=3.4'
```

I tried then installing pytest 4.6, as it is last series supporting Python 2.7 an 3.4. But got same error.